# Coordinate system changes after convertion from feature to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

For an hydrologic model I'm supposed to add a DEM as a .tiff data and another raster as .tiff data for roughness. So I exported my DEM as a .tiff without any problems. I have the roughness Information as a .shp file. So I used the "Feature to Raster" tool, to convert my .shp into a raster and then I exported the raster as a .tiff. When I try to add my roughness .tiff I get the error message  "Coordinate System of Raster does not match DEM".

According to the sources they have the same coordinate system. Before I started converting and exporting my layers they also have the same coordinate system. 
My theory is, that with the convertion process, the coordinate system has been changed without indicating it. Is that possible?

Comment: That's unlikely that the process changed the coordinate system. Check the geoprocessing environment to see if the output spatial reference is set. Otherwise, please edit your question with the extents before and after of your various datasets.

Comment: Hello mkennedy, a closer look on both sources revealed that they actually didn't have the same coordinate system. 

Thus, I managed to solve the problem. Thank you for your help anyway